# How to make "parameter info" work on Constructors in Android Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, android-studio

In AS (IntelliJ) you can see all of the overloaded method signatures for some method by pressing Ctrl+P:

[image: method signatures from Intent#putExtra revealed by pushing ^P]

However, this doesn't work with constructors as this helpful image illustrates:

[image: no drop down for constructors]

Why not?  Can this be enabled?